# Regex for a non-greedy match

Tags: java, regex

I've a String template which I need to process using regex. I need to get the list of `#condition #endcondition` blocks from the below template. I tried the following regular expression

```
String condition="\\#condition(.*)\\#endcondition";
```

But the below code

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile( condition,Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher( template );
while(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println("Found a match:[" + matcher.group()+"]");
}
```

The above system out prints everything from first `#condition` to last `#endcondition`. But I need to get two blocks. ie first `matcher.find()` should find the first `#if - #endif` block and second `matcher.find()` should find the second `#condition-#endcondition`.

Comment: You should use/make a parser. Regex is going to break down really fast here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a lazy quantifier:

```
"#if(.*?)#endif"
```

Also `#` is not a regex metacharacter so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: is the nomenclature 'lazy' or 'not greedy'?

Comment: @deepa bear in mind the solution here won't work for arbitrarily nested #if's.  Regexps don't do nesting well.

Comment: @Tony, strict regular expressions (in the Computer Science theory sense) can't do nesting at all. Some extensions make very limited nesting possible but extremely hard and with horrible syntax.

Comment: @Tony: 'not greedy' could refer to possessive quantification as well. Unless you consider possessive to be a weird subclass of greedy, I suppose.

Comment: Could you please help me to handle matching #if-#elseif even if nesting is there. Tony told that it is difficult to handle it.

Comment: @Tony I know this is an old thread, but I would have thought the correct nomenclature for this was reluctant, instead of 'not greedy'..?

Comment: @Adam Could be, I don't know.